# WPF ZIndex from more parents

Tags: wpf, z-index

If i have 2 canvases, one with ZIndex 1 and one with ZIndex 2.

The Canvas with ZIndex 1 has 2 children: 2 canvases, one with ZIndex 4 and one with ZIndex 6.

The Canvas with ZIndex 2 has 2 children: 2 canvases, one with ZIndex 3 and one with ZIndex 5.

And all these canvases has the same dimension and the same starting point, so i will see a single rectangle.

What will be the final order of drawing? 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 1,4,6,2,3,5?

In other words every parent will draw its children based on the ZIndex (so first the parent with ZIndex 1 and after that the parent with ZIndex 2? Or the ZIndex works at global level?

Comment: You could easily try that yourself. Anyway, ZIndex is only effective on direct child elements of the same parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Canvas` with a `ZIndex` of `2` will end up on top of the first one and the child `Canvas` with a `ZIndex` of `5` will be the visible one.

So a child `Canvas` of the `Canvas` with a `ZIndex` of 1 will not end up on top of a child `Canvas` of the `Canvas` with a `ZIndex` of 2.